# Can GitHub parse Markdown in README.txt?

Tags: github, markdown

Is it possible for GitHub to parse the Markdown in README.txt?

I don't want to name it README.md or README because most people don't know what *.md is or how to open it.  I insist on naming it *.txt because I want my users to be able to double click it and it should open in their text editor.

PyPI parses it properly.  Why doesn't GitHub?

Regards,

Delvian

Comment: I doubt this is possible (though I don't know), because txt files are generally formatted in such a way to ease readability without rendering, unlike markdown files

Comment: Github uses file extensions to identify the markup language used in a file. You can find a list of the supported file extensions and related markup languages in [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup#markups). The `.txt` file extension is not on the list for any markup language. It is treated as plain text only.

Comment: "txt files are generally formatted in such a way to ease readability without rendering, unlike markdown files"—actually, [Markdown was designed for this](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/): "The overriding design goal for Markdown’s formatting syntax is to make it as readable as possible. The idea is that a Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions."

Comment: "PyPI parses it properly. Why doesn't GitHub?"—because GitHub has different parsing rules than PyPI. Why _should_ any arbitrary site render a `.txt` file as Markdown? I suggest you just rename the file. You're probably overestimating the confusion this will cause.